# Numpy: What is the correct way to upsample an array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
octave:1> a=[1 2 3]
a =

   1   2   3

octave:2> k=[a;zeros(9,length(a))]
k =

   1   2   3
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
```

Is the below method the correct way to achieve it in Python:

```
>>> a=[1, 2, 3]
>>> np.append(a,np.zeros((9,len(a))))
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: Why is this "[upsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling)"? But yes, it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The octave solution results in a 10x3 matrix while your solution results in a 1-dimensional array with 30 elements.
I am assuming you want a matrix with the dimensions 10x3 right?

```
>>>a=np.array((1, 2, 3))
>>>k=np.vstack((a,np.zeros((9,len(a)))))
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```